# VBA: Second loop overwriting first loop

Tags: loops, excel, vba

Quick and, I assume, relatively easy question regarding VBA in Excel. I'm writing my first nested loop and I'm running into the problem where my second increment overwrites the first one. Here's the code:

```
Sub RandNumRang()
Dim i As Integer, Row As Integer, Col As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NoRows As Integer
Dim MinNum As Double, MaxNum As Double
Dim NumFormula As String
Col = 1 'Write random numbers on Column A
'Get the range and number of random values needed
For j = 3 To 4
    NoRows = ActiveSheet.Range("G" & j).Value 'No of random values needed
    MinNum = ActiveSheet.Range("E" & j).Value 'Min Range
    MaxNum = ActiveSheet.Range("F" & j).Value 'Max Range
    NumFormula = "=RANDBETWEEN(" & MinNum & "," & MaxNum & ")" 'Generate between Range
    i = 0
    For Row = 2 To NoRows + 1
    i = i + 1
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col).Value = i 'ID
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col + 1).Formula = NumFormula 'Random Value
        ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, Col + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=TIME(0,0,RC[-1])" 'Convert to time
    Next Row
Next j
End Sub
```

I'm trying to generate a set of random time intervals. The code does exactly what I want it to do except my values are being overwritten. The *j* loop will eventually have more than 2 increments but this code will have the same overwriting problem regardless. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with me specifying

```
For Row=2 To NoRows + 1
```

as the starting point of the nested loop but again this being my first run at a VBA script I figured I'd reach out because every fix I've tried has failed.  Thanks in advance, and let me know if you need any further details.

Also, I have attached a screenshot of the worksheet for reference:

[image]

Comment: In your example are you saying you want 30 random times based of min = 1 and max = 40 and then another 25 random times based off min = 41 and max = 80? So you should have 55 total `ID` values in column A?

Comment: Correct. Notice that currently the first 25 'IDs' have values between 41-80 and the last 5 have values between 1-40. This is where the overwriting occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for your example:

```
Sub RandNumRang()
Dim Row As Integer, Col As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim NoRows As Integer
Dim MinNum As Double, MaxNum As Double
Dim NumFormula As String
Col = 1
Row = 2

For j = 3 To 4
    NoRows = Range("G" & j).Value
    MinNum = Range("E" & j).Value
    MaxNum = Range("F" & j).Value
    NumFormula = "=RANDBETWEEN(" & MinNum & "," & MaxNum & ")"

    For Row = Row To (Row + NoRows - 1)
        Cells(Row, Col).Value = Row - 1
        Cells(Row, Col + 1).Formula = NumFormula 'Random Value
        Cells(Row, Col + 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=TIME(0,0,RC[-1])" 'Convert to time
    Next Row
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

So far as I can see it is performing as expected.  You set:

```
 Col = 1
```

This then remains the same for both loops.  Then you have:

```
For Row = 2 To NoRows + 1
```

So in your second loop you are always going to start at row 2, column 1 so it is always going to overwrite.

You either need to set Col to be 4 (or 5) in the second iteration or else keep a track of where you are in the rows and append to the end,

Comment: I'd like to append to the end because the number of iterations will be greater than 2 in the final output. I choose 2 iterations as an example to test it out. I was trying to do this earlier by looking for the first empty cell in column A after the first iteration, but I had no luck. Would you be able to provide the syntax for this?

Comment: Too quick! Thanks for looking into this.